# Missing Framework

Tags: high-sierra, recovery

I recently restored my computer from backup. However, one framework is missing: OnBoardingKit.framework. I did find the file in System/Library/PrivateFrameworks on another computer, but I could not put it in mine because of System Integrity Protection. I found a solution which was to do `csrutil disable` through recovery mode and then enable it again. But again there is another problem; my normal recovery mode fails to start leaving me with internet recovery mode with an older version. This version does not identify the command `csrutil`. Final option was to update via Appstore, but the Appstore app requires the OnBoardingKit framework. Are there any options that do not include wiping or re-restoring my computer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What precisely does restore mean? Running 10.13 installer drops all frameworks needed, so either there’s something really messed up with your hardware (hackintosh?) or the installer was bogus or failed in a very odd manner. Erase install is my next move, os I don’t know why you say except for that....

Comment: @bmike It is from backup. The computer is a macbook air, and I am unable to find a 10.13 installer.

Comment: The App Store has a 10.13 installer

Comment: @Mark exactly, I cant get to the Appstore.

Comment: @Mark: What is the name of the 10.13 installer. I cannot find it with a search in the App Store.

Comment: @BondedDust not now as it is now an old OS - the easy one to find now is e Mojave installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a application called [High Sierra Patcher](http://dosdude1.com/highsierra/) has an option that allows for the download of the High Sierra installer.

EDIT: This both fixed my frameworks and my recovery mode